# React deploy not serving images

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue where I deploy my React app the images are not showing. Works fine locally. I've set the homepage to a GitHub site http://ryandixon555.github.io/react-board-game and run

```
 npm build
```

then

```
 npm deploy
```

but still no images. I've also specified the homepage in the `package.json`:

```
"homepage": "http://ryandixon555.github.io/react-board-game"
```

Comment: any error on the browser console?

Comment: You can load the site and see for yourself using the above link. A syntax error in the manifest apparently (which would make sense), but no error that I can see

Comment: {
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}

Comment: Mine is not even deploying check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248045/react-web-app-not-working-or-deploying-correctly-now

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up and deployed using netlify, following this link and then copying my code over.