# React Web App Not Working or Deploying Correctly Now

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

[image: Not working after using GitHub Desktop to push to new repo]
I do not understand what I am doing wrong here. It worked absolutely fine before this. I was ready to deploy it to GitHub Pro using Pages, have the domain spragginsdesigns.com all registered and set up, etc. Still, now it doesn't even work locally. When I pushed it, I added a .gitignore for a node, but that didn't work either because node modules are over 10,000 files, so it refuses to let me upload. Please help. I have a panic attack figuring this out, and also I attached some pictures (a few days ago when it worked fine before GitHub).

[image: This was when it was working fine with a few minor issues I resolved like the favicon and a few others]

Answer (score 0):

don't have a panic attack. Chill for a second and breath.
Try and use

```
import {Fragment} from 'react'
 <Fragment> </Fragment>
```

instead of

```
 <>
```

[Fragments giving Unexpected token error in React 16.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596157/fragments-giving-unexpected-token-error-in-react-16-2)

**Edit**:

How to make a .gitignore file
Windows:
[How to create a .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-a-gitignore-file)

Mac:
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files

After you have added in the node_modules to the .gitignore file
follow this from:

**How to Deploy Your Project to GitHub**

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/

Comment: But, this is my code, will that work (I got it working anyway, but thank you I included you in my post):

`import React from `react``

`const HeaderButton = () => {`

`    return (`
 `       <>`
  `          <div className="mx-auto">`
   `             <a href="#about"><button className="see">Checkout My Portfolio<i `className="fas fa-eye"></i></button></a>`
 `           </div>`
  `      </>`
   ` )`
`}`

`export default HeaderButton`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone for the insane outburst I actually solved my own problem and it is working now, but would love help in how to properly deploy this to GitHub Pages.

I did this:

> Delete node-modules folder
> Delete package-lock.json
> Close editor, reopen and run `npm install --force if npm install`
> does not work for you, otherwise this is the answer.

[image: Working now, thanks everyone]

And thank you to  I am sure that [@bowl_of_rice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3022433/bowl-of-rice) would of worked too.

Comment: why did you delete node modules?

Have you heard of a .gitignore file?

Comment: I just npm installed them back, and no I am so new to this I want to deploy this today and I am failing to. Maybe you could message me here, respond here, or on Discord etc on how to do this so I can deploy it to https://spragginsdesigns.com right now? 

I could toss you a cup of coffee or something? 
Discord: Agent_Shadow99#0830
email: sales@shadowgaming.network